# Display image thumbnails with closing button in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget that should display images that user has chosen (something like they are shown on the screenshot) and I need to allow users to remove images from this widget. Is there already some widget capable of doing this in Qt or I need to implement such widget by myself?

So, basically I need to display a small image with small closing button in top-right corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can. Make a custom widget